# How to access Response Nodes in XML/SOAP using ColdFusion?

Tags: xml, soap, coldfusion

I am using ColdFusion 8.

I am trying to access my SOAP response nodes. I can't seem to access them though.  What I get is an empty array.  My SOAP response looks great. I get what I expect.

You can view the array and the SOAP response here:  http://dev.iqcatalogs.com/avcat/myiq/test-11.cfm

I have used Ben Nadel's blog post as a starting point (http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1809-Making-SOAP-Web-Service-Requests-With-ColdFusion-And-CFHTTP.htm)

I am parsing the XML like this:

```
soapResponse = xmlParse(httpResponse.fileContent);
```

I am trying to access the nodes like this:

```
responseNodes = xmlSearch(soapResponse, "//*[ local-name() = 'exhibitorlist' ]");
```

Some of my XML looks like this:

```
<exhibitorlist boothid="104686">
    <eventid>1</eventid>
    <eventcode>
      <eventname>Infocomm06</eventname>
      <boothnumber>1263</boothnumber>
      <companyid>408</companyid>
      <companynumber>173023</companynumber>
      <companyname>AMETEK Hunter Spring Products</companyname>
    </eventcode>
</exhibitorlist>
```

When I dump responseNodes, I get an empty array. I've tried a bunch of things, but nothing seems to get into the array.

Can you help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

have you tried:?

```
responseNodes = xmlSearch(soapResponse, "//ExhibitorList");
```

It should return all exhibitorlist elements in the document.

Comment: I just tried it. It doesn't work. Did you access my link to the SOAP? Take a peek and see if I am looking at the wrong thing.

Comment: It's a case-sensitive search. It looks like your nodes are actually < ExhibitorList> so the search would need to use that casing. I will update this answer.

Comment: Great catch Jason.  I was going off of his example.

Comment: Actually, it was a capitalization error.  The XML renders in the browser in lower case.  Jason, thanks for the catch.